# Science Fiction book about a present day military man on a future spaceship

Tags: story-identification, space, space-combat

A present day (1950s) military man finds himself in control of a future warship called Master Cruiser 12 12 12.

- The ship had a holographic control system is in the guise of a young woman called 'The Ever-Perfect Lieutenant'.
- I think the book may be part of an Ace Double.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book in question is "[Across Time](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?4947)" by [Donald Wollheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_A._Wollheim) (as David Grinnell)

Key Quotes;

> 'This is the **Master Cruiser 12-12-12**'

and

> "When the form of control which I represent  was first invented, **the
> very name given it by its makers was that of the Ever-Perfect
> Lieutenant.**  After me, there can be no crews."

For the record, it ***was*** released as an 'Ace Double' with the classic [Invaders from Earth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000K1WZT8)

You can read reviews of the story [here](http://mporcius.blogspot.com/2016/01/across-time-by-donald-wollheim-as-david.html) and [here](https://lazaruslair.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/across-time-david-grinnell-1957/).

Comment: And David Grinnell was a pseudonym (one of many) for Donald A Wollheim.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's been bugging myself and a friend for a month.

Comment: @brosil - No worries. If you liked the answer, don't forget to upvote it and mark it as "accepted"...